# Python - reorder pandas Dataframe rows based on column values

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe with 2 columns : id , antecedent_id
I would like a code to reorder the dataframe in the right order using antecedent_id.
The first id is the one with antecedent_id empty

Dataframe example:

| id | antecedent_id |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | id2 |
| id4 | id7 |
| id6 | id3 |
| id7 |  |
| id3 | id4 |
| id2 | id6 |
| id5 | id1 |

The dataframe reordered should be like this:

| id | antecedent_id |
| --- | --- |
| id7 |  |
| id4 | id7 |
| id3 | id4 |
| id6 | id3 |
| id2 | id6 |
| id1 | id2 |
| id5 | id1 |

I would like to find the fastest code to do that as I have a huge number of rows

Thanks you so much for your help !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For future reference, please provide code used to construct the dataframe so that it is easier for people to reproduce your problem statement and answer your question

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to sort the dataframe by values in a column:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": ["id1", "id4", "id6", "id7", "id3", "id2", "id5"],
    "antecedent_id": ["id2", "id7", "id3", "", "id4", "id6", "id1"]
})
sorted_df = df.sort_values("antecedent_id", ascending=False)
print(sorted_df)
```

This code chunk returns a sorted dataframe like so:

```
    id antecedent_id
1  id4           id7
5  id2           id6
4  id3           id4
2  id6           id3
0  id1           id2
6  id5           id1
3  id7
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion initially due to the phrase `reorder the dataframe in the right order using antecedent_id`, but this is very likely not what OP wanted. The outputs here don't match their expected output. What OP should have said is 'I have a directed graph (actually a path), where each node except the root has a unique antecedent (i.e. ancestor). Find this root, and perform a topological sort of the dataframe rows'